# Retrieving array values from JSON array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I am trying to retreive the values present in the JSON Array.However,my code is failing to get it executed.Below posted is how the file looks like.

```
{
  "meta" : {
    "view" : {
      "description" : "This data set shows the location of Baltimore City's Services.",
      "columns" : [{
          "cachedContents" : {
            "top" : [{
                "item" : "American Rescue Workers"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

My Apologies if my JSON file has got some syntax issues.I am trying to access the item element present in cachedContents.Below posted is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.get("https://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/hyq3-8sxr/rows.json", function (data) {
        $.each(data.meta.view, function (i, obj) {
            if (i == "name")
                $("#result").append("<p align='center'>" + obj + "</p>");
            if (i == "description")
                $("#result").append("<p>" + obj + "</p>");
            if (i == "columns")
                $.each(obj.i.cachedContents, function (i1, obj) {
                    $("#result").append("<p>" + "hi" + "</p>");
                });
        });
    });

});
```

Any suggestions would be highly helpful.

Comment: you never really access the item element...you do not event try to...

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON contains a lot of fields, and iterating through them and using `if` may have some performance issues.

You can directly access every member instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $.get("https://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/hyq3-8sxr/rows.json", function (data) {   
    $("#result").append("<p align='center'>" + data.meta.view.name + "</p>");
    $("#result").append("<p>" + data.meta.view.description + "</p>");

    data.meta.view.columns.forEach(function(c) {
      // here, 'c' is a column
      $("#result").append("<p>Column " + c.name + "</p>");
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: However,It is not printing the cachedContents in it  right?

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
$.each(obj[0].cachedContents, function(i1, obj) {
      $("#result").append("<p>" + "hi" + "</p>");
    });
```

Object[0] not "i".

Comment: does this code actually appends anything at all in #result?

Comment: No, I don't think so. The OP may want to iterate the obj to append something, not only the obj[0]